# How to comment strings of code in SOAP UI editor?

Tags: soapui, xml-comments

How to comment out strings of code in `SOAP UI` editor using shortkeys?

I have SOAP UI 5.2.1.

Comment: What do you mean by code in soapui editor? is it a soap request, or groovy script? clarify please.

Comment: @Rao I meant soap request.It is very hard way to comment out by <!-- -->

Comment: please someone help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76463462/how-to-uncomment-strings-of-code-in-soap-ui-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin for Notepad++ XML Tools.

It is very user friendly to comment out, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> back

Answer (score 14):

Actually there is a shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> will comment and uncomment the selected text.

Comment: not working for uncomment
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76463462/how-to-uncomment-strings-of-code-in-soap-ui-editor

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, `SoapUI` does not have **shortcut keys** to `comment xml` in the soap request editor. 
User have to manually comment the required elements.

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of plugin or workaround to fix that?

Comment: May be use xml aware editor/IDE for easy commenting and place the request in soapui request editor if desperately needed.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac the SoapUI shortcut is <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for XML editor.