# How to Uncomment strings of code in SOAP UI editor?

Tags: soap, soapui

I am trying to UnComment the text in SoapUI text with shortcut but not working.

I can comment the text simply press shortcut: Ctrl + /
like:     `</TextData>` to `<!--</TextData>-->`

but when i am trying to uncomment the same text- it is again commenting the text instead the uncomment

should be  `<!--</TextData>-->` to `</TextData>`

Actual result:  `<!--</TextData>-->` to`<!--<!--</TextData>-->-->`

**Note: this is occurring when comments text got old only then it is replicating otherwise for fresh action to uncomment the text its working fine**

I am using SoapUI version: 5.7.0

any idea what's wrong here !

Comment: I think you found a bug. You can log it for them but don't expect it to be fixed soon. https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/issues

Answer (score -1):

For version 5.6.0, ctrl + / does not uncomment code...  You have to go through and manually delete every instance of //.
They might've added the functionality with later versions.